# Showing a counter dynamically for JList items highlighted

Tags: java, swing

I have a program that I created for work. This program takes an uploaded file, reads it, and puts the data into a JList in the GUI. The GUI actually has two lists and the user is able to move items between the left and right list by highlighting them like usual with a JList and then hitting an arrow to move the items. The lists are multiple-interval selection.

One small addition I would like to add is some type of counter that shows the user how many items they have selected before they actually move them between lists. This would need to be dynamic so if the user holds control down and begins clicking the counter will continue to update the number of highlighted items.

As the lists are often quite large and a user might need to move an odd number of transactions between the lists (Think 300 transactions in left list and the user needs to move exactly 50) it would be beneficial to have this counter.

Can anyone think of how this could be done? I'm not sure how to add an action listener to just clicking on the items. Please also let me know if I need to elaborate any more.

Generally my question is can I create an action listener just for when a user clicks a item in a JList that updates a counter for the current selected indices? Also it would need to change when they no longer have selected an indice.

Comment: I would suggest tagging this with _swing_ as well so it properly reaches the "right" eyes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register a ListSelectionListener with your JList.

The listener could simply query how many rows are selected and update the number in the panel to that.  Perhaps use getSelectedValues().size().

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener-javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener-

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a good starting place honestly I didn't think this was possible but thank you again for giving me somewhere to start.